# Flyback converter with multiple DC outputs

Tags: transformer, flyback

I am trying to understand how (step up) flyback converters work, since I need to design one myself. I am not at all new to electronics and I understand the fundamentals behind them, but I am totally new to circuit designing and I am having some trouble with this project.

I need to design a DC-DC flyback converter such that \$V_{I}=2.7V\$ and it has three constant outputs: \$V_{O1}=5V\$, \$V_{O2}=-15V\$, \$V_{O3}=13.4V\$. I can only use one transformer. I have thought about buying one transformer with multiple inductors so that I can get multiple outputs at the same time (like [this one](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/10a6/0900766b810a6c67.pdf), for example).

Am I on the right track? Is there any possibility to find the transformer I need in the market or I will have to make one myself? How should I choose the inductance of the different coils in the transformer?

Comment: Those are plenty and uncommon voltages so you will most likley end up having to both wind it yourself and follow up with buck or LDO since you can only do full turns and it's unlikley 2.7 and 13.4 will have a common demoninator. First you design your primary with secondary ratio in mind, then you select your secondary windings accordingly.

Comment: As winny said you will never find a transformer with them specific values. I also think you will be extremely optimistic if you can wind it yourself in a single transformer. Could you not just use a single transformer and use a couple resistors to divide the transformers output to produce your supplys (of use other converters if you have the resource)?

Comment: @winny Thank you. How do I select my primary winding?

Comment: @sidA30 The problem I have is that the circuit I am designing must replace a broken DC-DC comverter. The original one used only one transformer and there is not enough space for more inside the original case. The problem about dividing the voltages with resistors would be the output current, I do not think that it will suffice, I would need to add more things. Thank you for the advice

Comment: You select it along with your other constrains on your primary side, MOSFET rating, allowable losses and so on. If you never have done an SMPS, flyback seems easy due to few components but it's a very complex task to optimize it due to everything being connected and related to everything else.

Comment: Wow, I was about to ask the same question myself. From what I found on the web so far, you'll probably have to wind the transformer yourself, or suffer heavy losses in the LDOs. Regarding how to choose inductance - check the datasheets for common flyback converter chips. Many of them, like [LT8301](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8301f.pdf) have detailed step-by-step calculation examples. Unfortunately not for multiple outs. I wonder if I can treat all secondary coils as one big coil with the sum of voltages for the purpose of calculations.

Comment: Here is another application note I found useful: [SLVA666](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva666/slva666.pdf) from TI

Comment: (Re. SLVA666: anybody think it odd for specifying two same voltage, polarity, amperage outputs sharing a common GND?)